# General approach for combining multiple foldrs over the accumulator type?

Tags: haskell

Recently I've come up with an idea for a function:

```
gridFoldr :: (a -> Grid -> Grid) -> [a] -> Grid -> Grid
gridFoldr f g xs = foldr f xs g
```

So I can easily combine multiple grid computations using the plain (.) operator:

```
let grid' = gridFoldr gridOp1 args1 . gridFoldr gridOp2 args2 $ myGrid
```

But I have a feeling that I'm missing some general haskell concept for using a similar approach without introducing a new function. Am I right? Is there some standard function / package / or maybe some clever Monad to do the task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are interested in "grid updates", i.e. in functions `Grid -> Grid`. This type is isomorphic to [`Endo Grid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Endo), which is a well-known monoid.

So, your function is similar to

```
foldGrid :: (a -> Endo Grid) -> [a] -> Endo Grid
foldGrid f = mconcat . map f
```

or even, exploiting more libraries

```
foldGrid = foldMap
```

Indeed, [`foldMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldMap) is a generalization of your function.

```
foldMap :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
```